# Drop log lines to Loki using multiple conditions with Promtail

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I want to drop lines in Promtail using an AND condition from two different JSON fields.

I have JSON log lines like this.

```
{"timestamp":"2022-03-26T15:40:41+00:00","remote_addr":"1.2.3.4","remote_user":"","request":"GET / HTTP/1.1","status": "200","body_bytes_sent":"939","request_time":"0.000","http_referrer":"http://5.6.7.8","http_user_agent":"user agent 1"}  
{"timestamp":"2022-03-26T15:40:41+00:00","remote_addr":"1.2.3.4","remote_user":"","request":"GET /path HTTP/1.1","status": "200","body_bytes_sent":"939","request_time":"0.000","http_referrer":"http://5.6.7.8","http_user_agent":"user agent 1"}
{"timestamp":"2022-03-26T15:40:41+00:00","remote_addr":"1.2.3.4","remote_user":"","request":"GET / HTTP/1.1","status": "200","body_bytes_sent":"939","request_time":"0.000","http_referrer":"http://5.6.7.8","http_user_agent":"user agent 2"}
```

My local Promtail config looks like this.

```
clients:
  - url: http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: testing-my-job-drop
    pipeline_stages:
      - match:
          selector: '{job="my-job"}'
          stages:
            - json:
                expressions:
                  http_user_agent:
                  request:
            - drop:
                source: "http_user_agent"
                expression: "user agent 1"
            # I want this to be AND
            - drop:
                source: "request"
                expression: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
          drop_counter_reason: my_job_healthchecks
    static_configs:
      - labels:
          job: my-job
```

Using a Promtail config like this drops lines using OR from my two JSON fields.

How can I adjust my config so that I only drop lines where `http_user_agent` = `user agent 1` AND `request` = `GET / HTTP/1.1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide multiple options they will be treated like an AND clause, where each option has to be true to drop the log.
If you wish to drop with an OR clause, then specify multiple drop stages.

https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/drop/#drop-stage

**Drop logs by time OR length**

Would drop all logs older than 24h OR longer than 8kb bytes

```
- json:
    expressions:
     time:
     msg:
- timestamp:
    source: time
    format: RFC3339
- drop:
    older_than: 24h
- drop:
    longer_than: 8kb
```

**Drop logs by regex AND length**

Would drop all logs that contain the word debug AND are longer than 1kb bytes

```
- drop:
    expression: ".*debug.*"
    longer_than: 1kb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clients:
  - url: http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: testing-my-job-drop
    pipeline_stages:
      - match:
          selector: '{job="my-job"}'
          stages:
            - json:
                expressions:
                  http_user_agent:
                  request:
            - labels:
                http_user_agent:
                request:

            #### method 1
            - match:
                selector: '{http_user_agent="user agent 1"}'
                stages:
                - drop:
                    source: "request"
                    expression: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
                    drop_counter_reason: my_job_healthchecks
                ## they are both conditions match will drop

            #### method 2
            - match:
                selector: '{http_user_agent="user agent 1",request="GET / HTTP/1.1"}'
                action: drop

            #### method 3, incase regex pattern.
            - match: 
                selector: '{http_user_agent="user agent 1"} |~ "(?i).*GET / HTTP/1.1.*"'
                action: drop
    static_configs:
      - labels:
          job: my-job
```

`match stage` include `match stage`.